# Parallel callbacks to subscriber

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0, parallel-processing, publish-subscribe

I have a WCF Service that Sends Data to Subscribed Clients. Using sequential loops the Process is quite slow as There are 3 loops within loops, For example;

```
for (int x = 0 ; x <= MasterTables.count - 1 ;x ++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y <= MasterData[x].count ; y++)
    {
        foreach (SubList subscriber in subscribers.ToList())
        {
            SendDatatoSubscriber();
        }
    }
}
```

So instead I Turned the Sequential Loops to Parallel Loops, which in turn was much faster, but down side was that server is Publishing Numerous Callbacks To a Single Subscriber at the same time, thus the transmission channel times out.

The SendDatatoSubscriber() event is a synchronous call, since i need the client to acknowledge that it has received the object and return a specific message to the server, as there are more events that are dependent on this result.

My web config, and the client Config are as below:

Service Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpSecure" closeTimeout="23:00:00" openTimeout="23:00:00" receiveTimeout="23:00:00" sendTimeout="23:00:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="2000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" portSharingEnabled="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="23:00:00" enabled="false"/>
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None">
              <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never"/>
            </transport>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="service.ClientBehavior" name=" service.DTSClient">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WcfDts.DTSClientEndpointBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpSecure" name="ClientNetTcp" contract="WcfDts.IDTSClient"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="WcfDts.DTSClientEndpointBehavior" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://127.0.0.1:8000/WcfDts/Services"/>
          </baseAddresses>
          <timeouts closeTimeout="23:00:00"/>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name=" service.DTSClientEndpointBehavior">
          <wsdlExtensions location="http://127.0.0.1/ service /Services/DTSClient.svc" singleFile="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name=" service.ClientBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType=" service.CustomUserNameValidator, service "/>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="CertName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
            <clientCertificate>
              <certificate findValue=" CertName " storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="2000" maxConcurrentInstances="2000" maxConcurrentSessions="2000"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="wsdlExtensions" type="WCFExtras.Wsdl.WsdlExtensionsConfig, WCFExtras, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Client Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="ClientNetTcp" closeTimeout="23:59:59" openTimeout="23:59:59" receiveTimeout="23:59:59" sendTimeout="23:59:59" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="100000" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="100000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="23:59:59" enabled="false"/>
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://BaseAdress:Port/Services/Service.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ClientNetTcp" contract="Sub.IClient" name="ClientNetTcp">
        <identity>
          <dns value="CertName"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup></configuration>
```

So my questions are:

1. Do i need to modify the config to curb the timeout situation
2. Or How do i make the Subscriber receive the callbacks parallel?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider making the SendData as below. Columns are parallel, rows are sequencial.

Subscriber 1 | Subscriber 2 | Subscriber 3 | ....

Send data 1  | Send data 1  | Send data 1

Send data 2  | Send data 2  | Send data 2

Send data 3  | Send data 3  | Send data 3

.....

I mean you can make the calls to send data for different subscribers parallel. So at a time you are sending data to multiple subscribers, but at the same time for individual subscriber you should make it sequential so you don't fall in the timeout.

Comment: Right that's what I did.. though I am still getting time outs.. now on the server side.. quite weird... must be a logical flow somewhere... could the time outs be caused by port sharing? As i use the port for sending data to a client and the same channel is used by the client to upload other data to the server... i am thinking of creating two separate services.. but if port sharing is not an issue then i would not like to touch my existing logic...please advice